# In-order message processing on serverless Azure Functions using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I need to process incoming messages on Azure. Each message will be associated with a specific entity – say, through an `EntityId` property – and messages belonging to the same entity must be processed in-order with respect to each other. At the same time, I would to preserve the serverless aspect of Azure Functions; if I have steady streams of messages for 1,000 entities, I'd like to have 1,000 concurrent executions of my function. I haven't found a clean way of achieving this. Service Bus queues have sessions, which are the closest implementation of my requirements, but they are not supported in Azure Functions: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/563. However, they seem to be supported in Azure Logic Apps. I'm thinking of creating an Azure Logic App that is triggered by a Service Bus queue using sessions ("Correlated in-order delivery using service bus sessions" template), then hooks to an HTTP-triggered Azure Function for processing messages. The Logic App's only purpose is to prevent multiple messages belonging to the same entity/session from being processed concurrently. Can someone provide some insight on whether this approach would work, and whether it has any caveats?

Comment: You can try to "drive" your workflow by your entity (entityid) and create according messages (jobs) in a queue, one for each entity. The job than collects all needed messages (from wherever they are stored) (best way to have them in a partition by entityid) and than process them in order. You can than drive your workflows in parallel. Durable Functions would be a candidate for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article from one of the Azure Function Team Member:
[In order event processing with Azure Functions](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428)

It uses [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) and [Azure Events Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/):

> Azure Events Hubs can handle billions of events, and [has guarantees around consistency and ordering per partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-availability-and-consistency#consistency).

For your scenario, each message related to the same `EntityId` has to go to the same partition.

The trick to have in order processing and let azure function scale independently is by pulling batches from event hubs, and preserve order.

You function should looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("EventHubTrigger")]
public static async Task RunAsync([EventHubTrigger("ordered", Connection = "EventHub")] EventData[] eventDataSet, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Triggered batch of size {eventDataSet.Length}");
    foreach (var eventData in eventDataSet)
    {
        try
        {
            // Process message in order here.
        }
        catch
        {
            // handle event exception
        }
    }
}
```

**I would recommend you to read the whole article, it is very instructive**

You can find the whole solution on Github:

https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-csharp-eventhub-ordered-processing

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I'd looked into that article, but I don't think it'd address my scenario, since Event Hubs only support up to 32 partitions ([Partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#partitions)). This limits parallelism to 32, whereas I'd like to be able to scale to 100s or 1000s of entities.

Comment: No worries :-) but why would you want to scale to an instance per entity ? Do you have any other concerns ? Not sure but using logic app you will also reach limits because you can only execute 300 000 actions per 5 mins and it could become very expensive

Comment: My concern is performance. Each entity will have a steady stream of messages which I'd like to process as soon as possible. I wouldn't want an entity's messages to be queued behind other messages belonging to other entities that happen to be on the same partition. Thanks for letting me know about the Logic App limits; that's the information I'm trying to gather right now.

Comment: You were right; not only is there the 300,000-action limit, but there's also a trigger concurrency limit of 50, which makes Logic Apps almost as bad as Event Hubs for lack of scalability.

Comment: You should not be worried too much about performance. In the article they processed 100 000 messages in few seconds. Also do you need to send infomation back to the user ?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it addresses the shortcomings of Logic Apps in the comments, which was what I specifically asked about in the question. I'll create a fresh question with a more generic discussion on scalable in-order processing of messages on Azure.

Comment: New generalized question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53781371/9685117. @Thomas, regarding your last comment: The article author only managed to achieve that throughput because the processing they do on each message is trivial. Even at merely 100ms per message, it would take 100,000 messages over 5 minutes to be processed, given that the degree of parallelism is limited to 32.

Comment: Somehow, in order processing is a tricky scenario... My feeling is that eventhub is design to ingest messages (it can ingest a million of messages per second) so scaling is not a problem. The way you process the messages on the other side is a very different problem. EventHub allow yous to decouple (async) ingest and processing.

Comment: Yes, but that only makes it suitable for the subset of scenarios which don't need any messages to be ordered, which is not the case for the majority of business applications. I'd want to know that a client credited their account *before* they made a purchase.

Comment: event hub is ordered